# Can I limit the back-up data in wallet.dat?

Tags: bitcoind, backup, wallet.dat, dogecoin

I want to know is it possible to back-up manually from wallet.dat. I am running Dogecoin daemon locally.

Scenario:

- say user (user1) have some dogecoin balance in addr1
- another user (user2) have dogecoin balance in addr2
- I want to back-up only user2 not user1

Is there any way to limit the back-up data in wallet.dat file?

Comment: Sounds like you should be using separate wallet files.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible without custom software or a lot of extra work. The wallet.dat file contains all the private keys, and the reference client doesn't have a way to split it up.